# Why is RadioGroup so tall in Google AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I created a RadioGroup and it turned out 79 pixels tall, even though I tried setting the height to "fit to content" or "fill parent".  There is lots of space between the two options, so I would like it to be shorter but it is ignoring the height option.  Any ideas?

Thanks for any pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the padding between the items with:

```
.app-RadioGroup-Item {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Although I suggest 2 or 4px (it's currently 8px).

If you want to mess with the actual size of the items, you can style the input element, something like:

```
.app-RadioGroup-Item input {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

Note you'd probably want to tweak more than just the height and width, and this doesn't look very good. I'd suggest sticking to only styling the padding if that's enough for you.

Comment: Two pixels looks great.  Thanks!